# javascript for loop with decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this `for` loop in order to show divs. But I get a strange error from the jQuery lib.

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: =10]

I have read about the problems with javascript decimals, but I still can't understand why this won't work:

```
for (var i = 10.00; i >= ui.value; i -= 0.25) {
    $("data_id=" + Math.floor(i) + "]").show();
}
```

When hiding the divs, I use this and it works fine:

```
for (var i = 0.00; i < ui.value; i += 0.25) {
    $("[data_id=" + Math.floor(i) + "]").hide();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using fractional numbers, if you .floor() them anyways? Try to use an integer loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the [ in the first loop, this will work:

```
for (var i = 10.00; i >= ui.value; i -= 0.25) {
    $("[data_id=" + Math.floor(i) + "]").show();
}
```

You should transform this into an integer loop, if you are .floor()-ing the numbers, anyway.

Comment: Please note the comment on the integer loop, as you are .show()-ing every component up to four times in a row, which is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your opening square bracket for the attribute equals selector:

```
for (var i = 10.00; i >= ui.value; i -= 0.25) {
    $("[data_id=" + Math.floor(i) + "]").show();
}
```

---

As others have mentioned, however, there is absolutely no reason to be using floats for this, since the call to `.floor()` essentially means you are calling `.show()` on each of the divs 4 times unnecessarily:

```
for (var i = 10; i >= ui.value; i--) {
    $("[data_id=" + i + "]").show();
}
```

This should accomplish exactly you want, in about a quarter of the work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `[` in your selector here:

```
$("data_id=" + Math.floor(i) + "]").show();
```

Which should be:

```
$("[data_id=" + Math.floor(i) + "]").show();
```

You should probably add `'` around the value of `data_id` as well, so the final result should be:

```
$("[data_id='" + Math.floor(i) + "']").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **never, ever** rely on floating point arithmetic for iteration/indexing variables. They may run you into strange situations, and even worse, different processors handle floating points differently. Your example doesn't seem to have any side-effects of floating points, but using floating points is really a bad practice.